# C - one dimensional array 24 elements with random integers, use a loop. Then put into a two dimensional array of 6 x 4 elements

Tags: c

Write a program that declares a one-dimensional array of integers with 24 elements. Fill the array with random integers (use a loop). Neatly output each element in the one-dimensional array.

Next, convert your one-dimensional array of 24 elements into a two-dimensional array of 6 x 4 elements. Neatly output each element of the two-dimensional array. The values will be identical to the one-dimensional array – you’re just converting from one dimension to two.

My problem is every time I fix the first part of this, the second part doesn't work and vise versa.
Any advice will help, here's what I have now:

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <time.h>

        #define ROW 6
        #define COL 4
        #define NUM_ELEMENT 24

      int main()
{
    int myInts[NUM_ELEMENT];
    int arr[ROW][COL], i, j;
    srand((int)time(NULL));


     for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) { 
            arr[i][j] = rand();
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

     printf("\n2-D: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }


    return 0;
}
I GOT IT NOW, THANKS EVERYONE!!
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the values in `arr`? You *print* them but you never assign to them.

Comment: As a hint for how to solve your problem, draw your one-dimensional array on a piece of paper (as 24 squares next to each other). Then you do the same with the two-dimensional array, draw it out as squares next to each other, ***right below the one-dimensional array***. I hope that should give you a hint about a possible way to solve the "conversion" problem.

Comment: Well, what does it mean "convert"? You might just initialize arr as a pointer to myInts or myInts[0], and access elements as it would be an array. Or you could copy items from 1dim to 2dim array.

Comment: format your code

Comment: I'm having trouble formatting/understanding the syntax, I'm in Intro to Programming. This is my first language.
I haven't learned pointer yet.

Comment: Whoever wrote this exercise probably intended it to be solved with pointers. Yes, it's possible to do without, but the solution would look uninteresting. You will learn more from doing it with pointers.

Comment: @anatolyg Very unlikely that an intro class would expect a pointer solution at such a beginner stage, and OP specifically said she hasn't even learned about pointers yet.

Answer (score 1):

This case is one of the few cases where pointer punning is acceptable.

```
#define ROW 6
#define COL 4
#define NUM_ELEMENT 24

int main()
{
    int myInts[NUM_ELEMENT];
    int (*arr)[ROW][COL], i, j;


    for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENT; i++) 
    {
        myInts[i] = rand();
        printf("%d \n", myInts[i]); 
    }
    printf("\n2-D: \n\n");

    arr = (int (*)[ROW][COL])myInts;

    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) 
        {
            printf("%d \t\t", (*arr)[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/STLp2r

Both arrays have to have the same memory representation and there are no alignment or aliasing issues.

Comment: When I copy your code into my Visual Shop, it's giving me the same output as mine. But when I used that link you attached, my code output worked. I'M SO CONFUSED
Thanks for attaching that by the way, I really like it.

Comment: I have no clue know what the `Visual Shop` is

Comment: @MissHopee But  if you mean Visual Studio - it works exactly as it should - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q38SV.png

Comment: I got it now. I had to remove a \n in the 1D code. How weird is that? And yes, I meant Visual Studio.

Comment: Although this is how I would probably solve the problem, if this is a course assignment the instructor might not take kindly to pointer punning by someone just learning C. The assignment sounds to me like the instructor wanted to see them figure out the mechanics of copying a 1D array to a 2D array.

Comment: Yes, I dislike how this course doesn't show how to write the syntax but it does make me think, that's for sure!
I edited the code in my question to the code I finally ended up with. Thanks!
We are learning pointer next, this got me excited to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed statement to initialise (copy) value from myInt 1D array to arr 2D array:

Observe this code and get your code fixed

```
Int count = 0;

printf("\n2-D: \n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = myInts[count++];
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

Comment: Your answer has the same problem OP's does -- it doesn't initialize `myInts`. All it will print is garbage.

Comment: @CareyGregory, This is not entire code, This is just code snippet to give you hint that this way you can initialize and print, So you need to replace this code with you existing code after you have initialized `myInts`